# How to get text from a windows control's textbox? and how do I know it's a textbox?

Tags: c#, winapi, ui-automation, sendmessage, windows-controls

I've used spy++ to find the right handle of the wanted windows control, which belongs to a standalone application which isn't managed. 
Note that the spy++ "property inspector" mentions that this window doesn't have any child (or parent) windows.

I've also managed to get back the name of the window with the following code:

```
   //the invokes are included aswell
    const int WM_GETTEXT = 0x000D;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IntPtr handle = new IntPtr(Convert.ToInt32("00070818", 16)); 
        int nChars = GetWindowTextLength(handle); //win32 function
        int length = 200;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);
        SendMessage(handle, WM_GETTEXT, length, sb);
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());           

    }
```

This window has a lot more information than it's title, and that's all I seem to get back with WM_GETTEXT (changing the value of length to 200 didnt help, was a long shot anyway).

Next, I've tried a different approach using UI Automation:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AutomationElement target = AutomationElement.FromHandle(handle);
    TextPattern textPattern = target.GetCurrentPattern(TextPattern.Pattern) as TextPattern;
}
```

but I got this error back:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in UIAutomationClient.dll
>
> Additional information: Unsupported Pattern.

To top it off, I've also tried using Microsoft Inspect.exe, but it failed to focus on the text in the window, both in UI automation and MSAA mode.

---

Does it mean that the data cant be achieved with UI Automation?? or should am I just using the wrong methods/types?

Is there another way to get the data from this window other than using GetWindowText, WM_GETTEXT, or UI automation??

I'm fairly new to this stuff, but I'm trying my best to learn. In addition I've have no current leads so any helpful comment/answer would be much appreciated!!
if you do answer **please be sure to include helpful keywords** so i'll be able to learn more about your solutions

Comment: This is a job for `System.Windows.Automation`. Ask for `TextPattern`.

Answer (score 2):

Labels (i.e. static controls) and text boxes are child windows with their own handles, hence they are visible to Spy++.  If your target Window has no children then it's not using a label or text box, it's painting the text itself, and you won't be able to retrieve it using `GetWindowText` or `WM_GETTEXT`.

The text might be exposed through [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx), the API used by screen readers.  Use [UISpy.exe or Inspect.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848721/where-do-i-get-ui-spy) to see if the text is accessible.

Comment: are there any other possibilities other that UI automation and the first method I've tried??

Comment: They are the two standard methods.  Other possibilities depend on how the application is written.  e.g. If it's using GDI you could inject a DLL and intercept the TextOut function.  But it might be using Direct2D.  Or it might be using an internal library to render text to a bitmap and outputting that.  You'd need to debug the application, find out how it's outputting its text and intercept that.  It's not straightforward.

Comment: so you're saying that getting into debugging with "API Hooking" will help me advance forward?? or did you refer to a different debugging method? 
thanks for all the help, and sorry for being such a noob

Comment: Not exactly.  I'm suggesting that you find out what the application is doing.  A debugger is one tool that might assist in this.  Once you know how the application is outputting text then API hooking might be one way of intercepting it.

Comment: could you name any relevant keywords/terms which i can use to continue my search for answers?? i'm just a little stuck with "debug" "external application" "how" "output" "text" T_T

Comment: The only thing I can think of is "reverse engineering".